# Return only the current and past months of the year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

Below is my code that will return all the months in a year.

```
SELECT TOP 12
DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1,0))
FROM sys.columns
```

What change must I make to only return the months that have passed and the current month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
select DATENAME(month, dateadd(month, number-1,0))
from master..spt_values
where type='p'
and number between 1 and MONTH(getdate())
```